# What are significant applications of the extended binomial coefficient?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, soft-question

The binomial coefficient \begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix} is well understood when $n$ is a positive integer.  According to Wikipedia, the definition can be extended by replacing $n$ by an arbitrary number α (negative, real, complex). My question is: what are some significant applications when α is

1. negative
2. rational
3. real
4. complex?

Comment: [Newton's Generalized Binomial Theorem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem)

Comment: when $α$ is rational, I think one of the application is expanding **generating functions** to power series. For example, the number of binary trees with $n$ nodes.